# Catch all promises in app

Tags: angular

I have a few components and modules, in these components i do some async requests. Is it possible to catch all callback from promises from whole app into the main component?

For example:
The First component have a promise

```
Activity.component.ts
...
ngOnInit(){
  this.checkActivity()
}
    private checkActivity(): void {
        this.http.get(this.url, {headers: this.headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then( response => {

            })
...
```

and the second component have a promise:

```
ads.component.ts
...
ngOnInit(){
  this.load()
}
        private load(): void {
            this.http.get(this.url, {headers: this.headers})
                .toPromise()
                .then( response => {

                })
...
```

And how can i catch these promises in app.component.ts ?

Comment: What do you mean by "catch a promise"? Do you want to access the value returned by the promise?

Comment: i mean if one of these promises return error (status 401,403 etc.) in the app.component.ts has to start some func

Comment: You can register a custom https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler. But that's mostly for logging. You shouldn't assume your application is still in a sane state after an exception reaches this handler. If you want your app to continue working after an exception you always need to catch as close as possible to where it's thrown.

Answer (score 3):

One way of informing your main component of every rejected promise is using a service:

- you register your main component as a callback with the service
- you notify the service of each rejected promise

A good implementation will be with [Observables](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services), but a very simple implementation could be doing this in each promise:

```
private checkActivity(): void {
    this.http.get(this.url, {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => ...)
        .catch(err => myService.notifyRejectedPromsie(err));
}
```

And in your main component:

```
myService.registerCallback(err => console.log(`Main component got ${err}`));
```

The implementation of the service would be:

```
public registerCallback(callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

public notifyRejectedPromsie(err) {
    this.callback(err);
}
```

Comment: Found a better source to learn about Observables: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

Comment: Yes it's normal realization, but i have a big project with ~30 services and components so it almost every has a promise. I search solution somethink like Promise.all().catch, but i think it's not possible